# kubernetes service discovery with specific endpoint (DNS)

Tags: azure, dns, kubernetes, kube-dns, azure-aks

I am using AKS cluster on Azure. I am trying to discover service using DNS (http://my-api.default.svc.cluster.local:3000/) but, it's not working (This site can’t be reached). With service IP endpoint everything is working fine.

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-api
  labels:
    app: my-api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
    app: my-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-api
    image: test.azurecr.io/my-api:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 3000
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: testsecret
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-api
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-api
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
```

> kubectl describe services kube-dns --namespace kube-system

```
Name:              kube-dns
Namespace:         kube-system
Labels:            addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode=Reconcile
               k8s-app=kube-dns
               kubernetes.io/cluster-service=true
               kubernetes.io/name=KubeDNS
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode":"Reconcile","k8s-app":"kube-dns","kubernet...
Selector:          k8s-app=kube-dns
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.10.110.110
Port:              dns  53/UDP
TargetPort:        53/UDP
Endpoints:         10.10.100.54:53,10.10.100.64:53
Port:              dns-tcp  53/TCP
TargetPort:        53/TCP
Endpoints:         10.10.100.54:53,10.10.100.64:53
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

> kubectl describe svc my-api

```
Name:              my-api
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"my-api","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port":3000,"protocol":...
Selector:          app=my-api
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.10.110.104
Port:              <unset>  3000/TCP
TargetPort:        3000/TCP
Endpoints:         10.10.100.42:3000
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

**From Second POD**

```
kubectl exec -it second-pod /bin/bash
curl my-api.default.svc.cluster.local:3000
Response: {"value":"Hello world2"}
```

**From Second POD website is running which is using the same endpoint but it's not connecting to the service.**

[image]

Comment: Why?  Usually you'd use the DNS name kube-dns provides (`my-api.default.svc.cluster.local`) and have the Service find the matching Pod by label matches, and not worry about the specific IP addresses at all.

Comment: @DavidMaze: Do I need to define dns config in deployment?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything special, no.

Comment: So, I am trying to access service using `my-api.default.svc.cluster.local:3000` and using selector in service instead of defining endpoints but I am getting `This site can’t be reached` error. If I access it using IP address everything is working normal.

Comment: Looking at your yaml, I see an indentation problem specifying the labels in Pod template. Hope that's not causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the indentation of your yaml file, I was able to launch the deployment and service successfully. Also the DNS resolution worked fine.

Differences:

- Fixed indentation
- Used `test1` namespaces instead of `default`
- Used containerPort `80` instead of `3000`
- Used my image

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-api
  name: my-api
  namespace: test1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: leodotcloud/swiss-army-knife
        name: my-api
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-api
  namespace: test1
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: my-api
  type: ClusterIP
```

[image: second-pod-test]

Debugging steps:

- Install tcpdump inside both of the kube-dns containers and start capturing DNS traffic (with filters from the second pod IP)
- From inside the second pod, run `curl` or `dig` command using the FQDN.
- Check if the DNS query packets are reaching the kube-dns containers.
- If not, check for networking issues.
- If the DNS resolution is working, then start tcpdump inside your application container and check if the curl packet is reaching the container.
- Check the source and destination IP address of the packets.
- Check the iptables rules on the hosts.
- Check sysctl settings.

Comment: In my case as well, dns is working from second pod when I use curl but application running inside that pod is not able to access it. Even when I use private ip in my browser it works but with DNS not working. (laptop is connected with VNET so private IPs and DNS should work). Please check the attached image in the question.

Comment: kube-dns works only within the cluster, hence the CNAMEs would not be resolvable from outside (laptop). What kind of application are we looking at? Generally applications use their own DNS libraries which might have their own quirks.

Comment: So, basically, at the level of kubernetes everything looks fine as I am able to access service through second pod with DNS but service is not exposing to azure node. I checked it by ssh into the node and curl the service. It's working with service endpoint IP but not with DNS.

Comment: @RonakPatel you are able to connect to the Kubernetes Services from the node by IP, because network routing to services work on the node level. But, you will not able to resolve FQDN name from your node, because in-cluster DNS, which contain records about your services available only inside pods, not on the node. I think, you can resolve that names from nodes, but you should manually setup DNS on your nodes and set your in-cluster DNS service IP address as a resolver for `*.local` zone.

Comment: @AntonKostenko : You are right. I recently found out that thing. I will post the specific solution once I test it or you can answer it how to set up private DNS manually on Azure and connect it to AKS. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Deployment` to deploy your application onto cluster where it will be consumed via a `Service` you should have no need at all to manually set `Endpoints`. Just rely on kubernetes and define normal selector in your `Service` object.

Other then that, when it makes sense (external service consumed from within cluster), you need to make sure your `Endpoints` ports definition fully matches the one on service (incl. protocol and potentially name). This incomplete matching is a most common reason for endpoints to be not visible as a part of service.

Comment: How can I access service using default DNS? `kube-dns` is already installed but when I try to access service using DNS it's not working. In any way, I need fix endpoint to access this service.

Comment: what do you get when you `kubectl describe svc my-api` ?

Comment: `Name:              my-api
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=my-api
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.10.110.145
Port:              <unset>  3000/TCP
TargetPort:        3000/TCP
Endpoints:         10.10.100.62:3000
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>`

Comment: are you sure your application listens and responds on 3000 ?

Comment: Yes. When I use provided endpoints it's working but not this one: `my-api.default.svc.cluster.local:3000`

Comment: I am able to access the service with IP address from inside and outside the pod.
But, with DNS, only able to access it from 2nd pod (when I use curl). But, again, application in that pod is not able to use this service with DNS.

Answer (score 0):

From the above discussion, what I understood is, you want to expose a service but not using the IP address.
Service can be exposed in many ways. you should look for Service type LoadBalancer.

Try modifying your service is follow :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-api
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: my-api
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
```

This will create a loadbalancer and map your service to the same.

Later you can add this loadbalancer to your DNS mapping service provided by Azure to give the domain name you like. ex: `http:\\my-api.example.com:3000`

Also I would like to add, if you define your ports as follow :

```
ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 3000
```

This will redirect traffic coming to port 80 to 3000 and your service call would look much cleaner for ex. `http:\\my-api.example.com`